# angular material icon sigifier

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, google-material-icons

I want to implement an Angular2 Material Input with Icon signifier on the left hand side of the floating label input. I haven't been able to find any documentation with proper code examples. Here is what I found on material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout :

[Expected outcome vs. my outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e8Oa.png)

Here is my try at the code:

```
  <i class="material-icons">email</i>
  <md-input-container align="center" color="primary" >

    <input type="email" mdInput placeholder="Email" required >

  </md-input-container>
```

can anyone please point me to a code example?

Comment: Please do not confuse Angular with AngularJS. AngularJS is version 1.x, while Angular is version 2+. Your code has mixed usage of Angular and AngularJS. `ng-model` is AngularJS, while the Angular equivalent is `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax error, I am fully aware of the difference since I come from a strong AngularJS background, the error was simply a typo.